# Galaxy S Advance Android update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, miui, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I've heard there are some Android alternatives. Like [miui](http://en.miui.com/) or Cyagenmod or [Mozilla OS](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefoxos/). I have Galaxy S Advance (GT-I9070) and i've heard Samsung is not going to provide any updates for my device. So, i got a few questions i should ensure before i done something stupid:

- if i install something from the mentioned above, shall i lose my guarantee/licenses?
- if i decide to install the software, should i perform some rooting of the device or something?
- if i do decide to install the software, what's the best one which shall not slow down my device (as i noted android 2.3.6 to be slow)
- could i use ICS update and shall it slow down my device or not?

Comment: Question #3 is too subjective to be answered here. The others have questions that have already covered that ground. Have a look around the [tag:rooting] and [tag:custom-rom] tags.

Comment: what in the world is "ROM"? Google knows only about CD-ROMs...

Comment: Google on android ROM or something like that

Comment: Or even better, just lookup our [tag wiki for ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)

Answer (score 1):

Miui en Cyagenmod are so called ROM's. ROM's are like modified versions of the original Android OS. They are built for various reasons, one of them being to add more features to your phone that aren't available in the stock OS (you could see those as your updates). Just Google about it because there is tons of information available about the particular subject.

The other questions are already answered but about the warranty. Most ROM's require your device to be rooted. I guess that rooting will void your warranty but then again, there's always something as UN-rooting.

Answer (score 0):

Re your fourth question:

- Starting in Russia, the S Advance is gradually [getting](http://www.sammobile.com/2013/01/07/samsung-start-jelly-bean-updates-galaxy-advance/) an upgrade to Jelly bean 4.1